# How to enable beep sound using zxing library?

Tags: android

i have used the implementation is

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

and i am not using IntentIntegrator so please give me some suggestion

Comment: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/issues/90

Comment: Thanks, It works for me, But it gives notification sound. How to change to beep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code provided above in the comments gets the default ringtone sound:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(ba.context, notification);
r.play();
```

Instead, you should add a Uri to the sound you want by adding a sound to the raw folder in your project:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    try {
        Uri beepSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/beep.wav");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, beepSound);
        r.play();

            ... other barcode scanning result handling
    } catch (Exception e) ....
```

OR use ToneGenerator:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    try {
        ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
        tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);

        ... other barcode scanning result handling
    } catch (Exception e) ....
```

Comment: Hi I am using xamrain forms, how does one call the function handle result from say a button in the ui ? .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this) 
                .setBeepEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rajan Mourya,change your code to this

```
try {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + MainActivity.context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.t_tone);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(MainActivity.context, sound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
```

where raw is a created folder under res that contain your sound file